# VisualStudio cannot run code on MonoGame

Tags: c#, windows, monogame

I am having issues with running code that is written in VisualStudio 2015 in MonoGame 3.5.

My two versions are compatible, from all I can see. VisualStudio has no issues running Console application codes, and also connects to Unity just fine (I can write code in VisualStudio for Unity and it runs).

I can also open up MonoGame and convert png files into xnb's to use in VisualStudio. It is only when I try to actually run the VisualStudio code and Windows tries to open MonoGame, it fails.

To better show what is happening, I created an empty project specifically by clicking "MonoGame for Windows" in VisualStudio, and called it EmptyGame. By default, running this should yield a cornflower blue screen. Instead, it shows this error message:

[error message Ctrl+F5 MonoGame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjooI.png)

I then tried to debug the completely default code (it shouldn't have any bugs as it is the default provided by VisualStudio but I did it anyway) and got this:

[debugging error message VisualStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWb5Z.png)

I have tried googling this error message and not gotten very far. Somebody had a similar error message for Duality2D (https:// forum.adamslair. net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=732) but the answers they gave don't apply here I don't think...

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling both programs, making sure that I ticked VisualStudio 2015 in the MonoGame installation, and turning off my anti-virus while trying to run (Ctrl+F5) - I was desperate at this point.

Anyone got any ideas? I can't possibly be the first person to have issues trying to get VisualStudio and MonoGame to communicate, but Google has gotten me nowhere. I just found this website which had a lot of great reviews so hopefully someone here has an answer for me!

Appreciate it!
-M.

Comment: You're running the code from your home drive, which is an UNC path, which is not supported for whatever action is occurring during the running of the base `Game()` constructor. Probably it's a call to `ExtractAssociatedIcon()` to display an icon somewhere. See also [ExtractAssociatedIcon gives exception in network share using powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821615/extractassociatedicon-gives-exception-in-network-share-using-powershell). Develop on a local drive instead.

Comment: I was using the PC provided by my workplace, where they advise us to use that drive for everything. Moved everything to (D:), which we are not really supposed to for different reasons, and everything works perfectly! Thank you thank you! I was scared that it was a Windows-related problem!