# `FileNotFoundException` for network-shared files that do exist. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, network-shares

I need to get a default file icon from shared file. I faced some problems with this and found [the question "How to get the associated icon from a network share file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842226/how-to-get-the-associated-icon-from-a-network-share-file).

But now I have another problem with shared files, it looks as if they did not exist. Here is my code:

```
public static Icon ExtractAssociatedIcon(String filePath)
{
    int index = 0;

    Uri uri;
    if (filePath == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("'{0}' is not valid for '{1}'", "null", "filePath"), "filePath");
    }
    try
    {
        uri = new Uri(filePath);
    }
    catch (UriFormatException)
    {
        filePath = Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
        uri = new Uri(filePath);
    }
    if (uri.IsFile)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath);
        }

        StringBuilder iconPath = new StringBuilder(260);
        iconPath.Append(filePath);

        IntPtr handle = SafeNativeMethods.ExtractAssociatedIcon(new HandleRef(null, IntPtr.Zero), iconPath, ref index);
        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return Icon.FromHandle(handle);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I always get `FileNotFoundException` and I don't now why. `filePath` is OK, and I can access these files through the Explorer. I tried to create `FileInfo` instance from `filePath` (I read somewhere that it may help) but still nothing.

What I'm missing?

Comment: you should have access to Network location as well as your file path should be something like this: `\\ServerName\FolderName\FileName.txt` and in C# `@"\\ServerName\FolderName\FileName.txt"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472168/check-if-directory-exists-on-network-drive (even though the present question is about `File.Exists` and the older question is about `Directory.Exists`).

Comment: I'm going to guess that your running in a process like IIS and that runs with privileges that don't have access to network resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, `File.Exists` and `Directory.Exists` have some problems resolving drive letters that are mapped to a network share. They might simply not see these drives, so they report `false` even though the path points to a valid file.

If you use UNC paths (`\\server\share\file.name`) instead of drive letters, it might work, so resolve a drive-letter-bassed file path to a UNC path first and pass the latter to `File.Exists`. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17481443/240733) to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17472168/240733) for an example how to do this.